# VBA update or delete row in CSV

Tags: sql, vba, csv, ado

I am working on a project where I have to use CSV as a little SQL database.
I am communicating with this database using VBA.

I would like to know if there is a way to UPDATE (or DELETE) an existing row (records).

I've managed to insert new row with the following code but I am unable to modify existing row.

```
Sub WriteData()
    ' some Code
    Open str_Path For Append As #1
    str_Data = ' Semicolon separated value in a string
    Print #1, str_Data
    Close #1
End Sub
```

I have also try with ADODB Recordset object but I am unable to create a proper connection string that understand that the delimiter is ";".

Thank you very much for any help or ideas :)
Best,
Max

Comment: It would help your question to post the code you used when you tried to perform an update.

Comment: I've not managed to try. I've read several stuff online but I don't find what I'm looking for ! (Maybe I am also to newbie to understand some solutions)

Comment: I don't think you can update a row in a CSV using ADO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, probably using VBA's `Open` statement, but I would use Excel, as follows.

```
Dim xlApp, xlWb, xlWs

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If xlApp Is Nothing Then _
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set xlWb = xlApp.Open("C:\blahblah.csv")
Set xlWs = wlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

xlWs.Row(1).EntireRow.Delete 'Change 1 to whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileSystemObject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

With this you can easily browse, read, delete, and append lines to a text file.